# Convert PDF to CSV via Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to take data from a webform that is generated in pdf format and migrate it to csv so I can use my limited powershell knowledge to automate VM builds.  This is all done on linux as well.  This is what I have so far and that seems to work, but I need to automate it all so I need to use wildcards as the file names will change.

```
pdftotext  -nopgbrk './AndyTest-2 - Linux - Debian 10_13.pdf' test.txt

Import-Csv test.txt | Export-Csv test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Cool - it sounds like you've already got 90++% of the solution.

Q: Why not just call your PS script with parameters?

EXAMPLE:

```
$PdfFile=$args[0]
$TxtFile=$args[1]
$CsvFile=$args[2]
pdftotext  -nopgbrk $PdfFile $TxtFile
Import-Csv test.txt | Export-Csv $CsvFile
```

One possible "gotcha" is that apparently have spaces in your .Pdf filenames.  One solution is to quote your variable, e.g.:

```
"$PdfFile"
```

Look here for more ideas:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a527307-5bb1-40fa-94b3-9af0a3e181f3/
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e51b6f4-4adf-4253-8228-c410032209f7/

'Hope that helps!